# get elements sum from array Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

i have an array that contains another array and i wanna get specifics elements sum

Array

```
    array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "shop_id" => 1
    "delegate_id" => 2
    "items" => array:3 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "product_id" => 2
        "price" => 4.75
        "quantity" => 1
      ]
      1 => array:3 [▼
        "product_id" => 6
        "price" => 18.5
        "quantity" => 1
      ]
      2 => array:3 [▼
        "product_id" => 10
        "price" => 88
        "quantity" => 2
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

i need to get the sum of price

any ideas to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If there is relationships there is a better approach. As the data you have given you could call sum twice and make it work.

```
collect($array)->sum(function (array $shop) {
    return collect($shop['items'])->sum('price');
});
```

This will sum each individual shop and the sum amount would be the sum of each shops items.